# How to apply DDD with Breeze.WebApi.EFContextProvider?

Tags: entity-framework, domain-driven-design, breeze

I use breeze.js on the client and Breeze.WebApi on the server.
I build my EF POCO entities with methods and domain services. There are some background processes running on the server which use the business domain just fine.

The problem is that **I'm not sure how to use the domain methods and services when saving client side changes on the server with EFContextProvider?**

For example:
If client adds a new *Task* and specifies that this new task should generate new *Actions* for each existing *Invoice* (breeze SaveOptions.Tag), then a domain service AddActionsToInvoices should be invoked to add the necessary actions to existing invoices. Finally the new task and all new actions should be saved during the same transaction.

Generally, to be able to work with the domain I need to ensure that aggregate roots are fully fetched when calling domain methods and that all changes are persisted at the end.

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty open ended question. I think I understand your general point to be that at least some saves do more than store changed data in a database. They are business processes in their own right which just happen to also save data.

You could try to run these all through a single "SaveChanges" Web API method. But that feels wrong. Pretty soon your `SaveChanges` method becomes a giant dispatcher to helper methods.

Have you looked at **["named saves"](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/saving-changes#NamedSave)**? That feature was designed for what sounds like your scenario. I think it beats sending a "tag" and trying to dispatch to the appropriate server-side method based on the tag value.